# Several Gradle errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I try to use FireBase in my App but I get several Gradle error messages:

First, look at my build gradle (module app):

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.finalchat"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I sync my project, it throws me this **error** message:

- Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()' Possible
  causes:The project 'Finalchat' may be using a version of the
  Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
  'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
- The project 'Finalchat' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin

**Edit: I read some questions regarding this problem, but my problem was not solved.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update build-tools via SDK Manager, then update your `build.gradle` to use the most recent `buildToolsVersion` (27.0.3 (stable), 28.0.0 (preview) atm).

Also replace all `compile` with `implementation`, the IDE will give you a warning. Also you may need to update your dependencies.

Do not downgrade, as this will break some day later.